# Rails: Error installing activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a rails project, and i want to install the **activeadmin gem**. So i have added this to the *gemfile*:

```
gem 'activeadmin'
gem "meta_search"
```

The problem is that when i run the **bundle** command, i get this error:

> Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
>     In Gemfile:
>       activeadmin (>= 0) ruby depends on
>         meta_search (>= 0.9.2) ruby depends on
>           actionpack (~> 3.0.0.rc2) ruby
>
> less-rails (>= 0) ruby depends on
>         actionpack (4.1.8)

Do you know how can i fix this?

Comment: tried running `bundle update` ?

Comment: Yeah, it's the same error

Comment: Take the `meta_search` gem out. The later versions of `activeadmin` use `ransack`

Comment: Also, use `gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'` instead of just `gem 'activadmin'`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using rails 5.1 or above

```
gem 'inherited_resources', git: 'https://github.com/activeadmin/inherited_resources'
gem 'activeadmin', git: 'https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin'
```

If you are using rails 4

```
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin/activeadmin', branch: :master
```

If you are using rails 4 with gem 'mongoid','~> 5.0.0' then add

```
gem 'activeadmin',  github: 'Zhomart/active_admin', branch: 'mongoid-old'
```

Try this. Hope it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

In place of both gems in your Gemfile, replace them with:

```
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using rails 5 You have to install inherited_resources gem with active_admin

```
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'
gem 'inherited_resources', github: 'activeadmin/inherited_resources'
```

Try this.Hope it's helpfull